# Hangfire works only when accessing the hangfire dashboard site, not working continue in backround

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have published my health API on the IIS server. I am worried as my jobs are not continue running on hangfire dashboard. When I check and access the site, it starts working and getting success and there are no jobs getting succeeded after closing the site from the browser.

I am looking for a solution on how I can make my jobs active and working at the defined frequency in the background on hangfire in order for execution.

For example, I have 4 jobs I have executed in 1-hour interval but when I check there is no job record for the execution in each 1 hr interval. But when I access the site then only I can see that job is recently executed.

Comment: Have you read this ? https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Comment: By the way, its resolved! I have set the idle timeout 0 in IIS server advanced settings which is by default set as 20. The application should always be running in background in order to execute cron jobs.